# Виртуальное окружение содержит библиотеку, но консоль cmd её не видит

Tags: python, windows, visual-studio-code, cmd, импорт

Я работаю в виртуальном окружении `Python 3.10.5`
Я могу запустить отладку открытого файла используя локальное виртуальное окружение `.venv_my_project`. Если я импортирую в файле следующим образом:

```
import numpy as np
```

То файл запускается и успешно работает с `Numpy` объектами.
Если я активирую виртуальное окружение в консоли и пытаюсь сделать следующее:

```
(.venv_my_project) D:\path\to\project> python

Python 3.10.5 (tags/v3.10.5:f377153, Jun  6 2022, 16:14:13) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

>>> import numpy as np
```

Я получаю:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

1. `Numpy` находится в виртуальном окружении по пути `D:\path\to\project\.venv_my_project\Lib\site-packages\numpy`
2. pip не видит `Numpy`:

```
(.venv_my_project) D:\path\to\project>pip uninstall numpy
WARNING: Skipping numpy as it is not installed.

(.venv_my_project) D:\path\to\project>pip uninstall numpy3
WARNING: Skipping numpy3 as it is not installed.
```

3. Это именно тот `Numpy`, который загружается в файле. По крайней мере, если я в контекстном меню на токене `numpy` выберу "Перейти к определению", то меня кинет именно в ту папку в том виртуальном окружении.
4. Я использую `VS Code`. Я обнаружил эту проблему примерно 1.5 месяца назад.
5. Выполнение `sys.version_info` в файле возвращает:

```
sys.version_info(major=3, minor=10, micro=5, releaselevel='final', serial=0)
```

6. Я пытался добавить в `sys.path` в интерактивном режиме следующие пути:

- `os.getcwd()`
- Путь до виртуального окружения
- Путь до Numpy в виртуальном окружении

Это не помогло мне.

Comment: Ну а `pip list` что выводит?

Comment: Такое впечатление, что у вас запускается не тот python. Проверьте переменную PATH - какая папка с python встречается раньше других. Обновите PATH, чтобы путь `D:\path\to\project\.venv_my_project\Scripts` был в самом начале. Ну или запускайте `python` с полным путём `D:\path\to\project\.venv_my_project\Scripts\python`

Comment: @HerrAskin в консоли в виртуальном окружении выводит несколько библиотек. Среди них нет `Numpy`.

Comment: @PakUula я работаю с двумя проектами в разных версиях `Python` и текущий проект не является приоритетом. Могут ли быть иные причины проблем? Я не хотел бы менять PATH, тем более, что версия, полученная в файле и так совпадает с версией, полученной в консоли.

Comment: numpy, кстати, в десятом питоне, по-моему, еще не работает...

Comment: @Глеб есть ли ссылка на первоисточник для этого утверждения? Я полагал, что `Python` обратно совместим для минорных версий. Не значит ли это, что `Numpy` должен работать с момента релиза?

Comment: @Aycon, если `pip list` не выводит `numpy`, то он видимо в этом виртуальном окружении и не установлен. А импорт в файле происходит, видимо, с использованием библиотек, установленных непосредственно в системе (ну или из второго проекта, нужно с `VS Code` разбираться, на какой `python` он ссылается). Попробуйте в этом виртуальном окружении установить `pip install numpy`.

Comment: У меня десятый питон (был) и numpy на нем тупо не устанавливался. Сейчас, похоже, уже догнал.

Comment: @HerrAskin это может быть. Я использовал `--system-site-packages` при создании окружения. Есть ли способ использовать в том числе и системные пакеты из консоли? Разве поведение консоли в данном случае не должно совпадать с выполнением в файле?

Comment: @Aycon, а смысл создавать виртуальное окружение, если используются пакеты из системы? Смешивать пакеты вряд ли получится. Разница в поведении кроется в настройках `VS Code`. Я с ним не работал, но в `PyCharm` есть способ задать используемый интерпретатор (ну и зависимости с ним). Вы можете скопировать все пакеты из системы с помощью `pip freeze > requirements.txt`, а затем в своем новом виртуальном окружении `pip install -r requirements.txt`.

Comment: @HerrAskin смысл есть, не могу согласиться насчёт настроек. Мало места для аргументации.

Comment: @Aycon, в консоли деактивируйте виртуальное окружение и пользуйтесь системными пакетами и библиотеками.

Comment: Может есть возможность какую-нибудь симлинк создать в виртуальном окружении на библиотеку в системе? Это так, мысль проскочила...

Comment: @HerrAskin в виртуальном окружении лежат нужные для проекта пакеты, которыми я не хочу засорять систему. Это и есть смысл, о котором вы спросили. Нет, это не вариант. Симлинк звучит как костыль. Нужно решить проблему в корне, я полагаю.

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151198/discussion-between-aycon-and-herraskin).

Comment: Как рекомендация, используйте poetry 1.2.0 вместо venv. И по делу, проблема вероятно в совместимости окружения и интерпретатора, попробуйте запустить  в консоли таким образом "python -m venv_my_project" и уже попробовать вызвать pip list

Answer (score 0):

Если вы работаете в VScode, то нажмите на python 3.10.5 внизу, в появившемся меню выберите "Введите путь к интерпретатору. Пройдите по пути где находятся ваш установленный python. Выберите python 3.10.5.exe или около того. Numpy должен появится. Если не появится, попробуйте установить numpy снова.

Comment: Ваш ответ минусанул не я. Путь уже указан верно. Повторение процедуры ничего не изменило. Я не хочу устанавливать второй numpy. Файл же находит где-то первый, возможно в системе. Пожалуйста, см. чат.

Comment: Если не хотите скачивать второй numpy, то удалите первый через pip uninstall numpy

Comment: пожалуйста, прочитайте вопрос. Результат команды я приводил.

Comment: Что ж, в таком случае я могу лишь предложить использовать pycharm у которого есть встроенная система установки библиотек.

Comment: пожалуйста, прочитайте новые сообщения в чате.

Comment: Я не хотел бы отдавать награду этому ответу, потому что он не верен. Пожалуйста, прочитайте чат, возможно, вы найдёте правильный ответ.

Comment: У меня вопрос более развёрнутый, чем этот ответ, который на самом деле не отвечает на вопрос.

Comment: Виртуальное окружение отделяет ваш код от глобальных настроек Python. Если вы запускаете venv, то вам нужно установить numpy уже для него.